# Outlook syncronization log errors with Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

Outlook 2007 for a user is receiving "Synchronization Log:" emails from the Exchange 2010 server.

The user has no difficulty sending/receiving emails.

These log emails contain errors such as the following:

```
Microsoft Exchange offline address book
Not downloading Offline address book files.  A server (URL) could not be located.
0X80004005
```

This particular email can come in to the inbox every minute! :

```
Synchronizer Version 12.0.6606
Synchronizing Mailbox 'Joe Smith'
Error synchronizing folder
[80040107-501-0-1440]
The client operation failed.
Microsoft Exchange Information Store
For more information on this failure, click the URL below:
http://www.microsoft.com/support/prodredirect/outlook2000_us.asp?err=80040107-501-0-1440
Done
```

Can someone please help? Is there an Exchange setting that can prevent these emails from being sent?

Answer (score 1):

According to the OAB errors message, I would suggest first to check the link to OAB that appears at "Server Configuration -> "Client Access" sub tree of Exchange MMC. There will be an Outlook Address Book tab. Make sure client is able to properly resolve and connect to the link published on the server. In addition you need to make sure that the server that generates OAB is online and available.